# Dragging and dropping datasource fields in xpages causes designer 8.5.3 to crash

Tags: xpages

I am having an issue with Designer 8.5.3 crashing when I try to drop and drop fields from the data palette on to a custom control or an XPage.  Occasionally the drap and drop will work, but with no apparent reason or consistency.  Most of the time(98%) designer crashes.

I am currently using Windows XP on a corporate imaged laptop.
I have errors similar to the one below listed for the databases that I have tried to work with.

The project was not validated due to "Can not create a Resource at the location : jnsf:/Local/databasetest.nsf/bin". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and validating it since it may be inconsistent   databasetest.nsf        Unknown JavaScript Problem

I have read a related post and tried the suggestions, but they did not seem to work.  Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this happen with all data sources? Would you be willing to share the database with IBM in order to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened a PMR with IBM yet? If not, do so an supply them the crash logs, dumps, ...

Comment: Just as a follow up, I tried to open a PMR with IBM.  Apparently in the system, Designer 8.5.3 is a non supported product.  This was told to me by both the person in support that I spoke with and my IBM sales rep(after I was advised by support).

Comment: I can not imagine that. Are you sure? Do you have Domino licences. If so, you should get support for Domino Designer. http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Overview/Software/Lotus/Lotus_Domino_Designer